# 'partners may not have the same buy-in in projects' vs 'partners may not have the same buy-in of projects'?

Tags: prepositions

I do not know which one is the correct preposition to use in the following example. 
'partners may not have the same buy-in in projects', seems to be more correct but 
'partners may not have the same buy-in of projects'

Comment: Don't you buy-in _to_ a thing?

Comment: It depends on what you mean.  If the purpose of the partners' buy-in(s) is for the partners to become a part of the project(s), then you use "in."  If the partners' buy-in accumulates a fund that acquires the projects themselves, then you use "of."

Comment: It really doesn't flow well, no matter which preposition you try to shoe-horn in there.  I suggest *Project partners may not have the same buy-in [with/without such-and-so].*

Comment: I think "buy-in for each project" sounds a bit better, but restructuring the sentence lik @aparente001 suggests is also a good option.

Comment: @JRodge01 - It completely depends on the situation.  There are so many ways of avoiding preposition snafus.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I think I will go with restructuring the sentence like aparente001 stated.